# Informix stored procedure return values

Tags: java, stored-procedures, informix

I need to create a stored procedure which returns a select statement, say about 4-5 columns with values.

I need to call that from a Java app so I can't put the output into a temp table as that temp table won't be accessible from another session. So I basically need to call the stored procedure then create an array list from the return values.

The returned data will be `select * from table`.

Answer (score 0):

Treat the stored procedure as if it was a SELECT statement that returned the values.

In languages such as ESQL/C, you prepare the 'EXECUTE PROCEDURE' statement, then declare a cursor for it, followed by OPEN, FETCH in a loop and CLOSE.  The analogous operations should work in JDBC and Java too - with the possible difference that you may not need to separate the prepare and execute phases.

---

I can spell 'Java' - let's think; it starts with 'C'...doesn't it?  Like 'C'?

In ESQL/C, you would write (ignoring error checking and variable declarations):

```
EXEC SQL PREPARE prep_stmt FROM "EXECUTE PROCEDURE CursoryProcedure(?,?,?)";
EXEC SQL DECLARE cursor_nm FROM prep_stmt;
EXEC SQL OPEN cursor_nm USING :hostvar1, :hostvar2, :hostvar3;
while (SQLCODE == 0)
{
    EXEC SQL FETCH cursor_nm INTO :receiver1, :receiver2, :receiver3,
                                  :receiver4, :receiver5, :receiver6;
    if (SQLCODE != 0)
        break;
    ...use the values in the receiverN variables...
}
EXEC SQL CLOSE cursor_nm;
EXEC SQL FREE cursor_nm;
EXEC SQL FREE prep_stmt;
```

The three placeholder question marks represent the input values passed into the stored procedure; the values are passed to it in the OPEN operation.  The stored procedure may return (zero or) one or more rows of data; each row gets handled in turn as shown.

The only difference between that code and handling a SELECT statement is the PREPARE line:

```
select_str = "SELECT * FROM A_Table WHERE Col1 = ? AND (Col2 = ? OR Col3 < ?)";
EXEC SQL PREPARE prep_stmt FROM :select_str;
```

Now - you are going to have to work out how to translate the ESQL/C above into JDBC.  You probably don't need to worry so much about the FREE operations - in ESQL/C, even, one of those two may be redundant (but harmless).  But the PREPARE, DECLARE, OPEN, FETCH-in-a-loop and CLOSE sequence will need to be replicated.

---

I'm assuming you can read the manual and know how to write an Informix stored procedure, but just in case:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CursoryProcedure(i INTEGER, j CHAR(10), k DATE)
    RETURNING CHAR(20) AS v1, INTEGER AS v2, DATE AS v3, 
              VARCHAR(255) AS v4, INTEGER AS v5, INTEGER AS v6; 
    DEFINE v1 CHAR(20);
    DEFINE v2 INTEGER;
    DEFINE v3 DATE;
    DEFINE v4 VARCHAR(255);
    DEFINE v5 INTEGER;
    DEFINE v6 INTEGER;
    FOREACH SELECT *
              INTO v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6
              FROM Table
             WHERE Col1 = i AND (Col2 = j OR Col3 < k)
        RETURN v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6 WITH RESUME;
    END FOREACH;
END PROCEDURE;
```

This is a more or less minimal procedure that does the job -- you wouldn't often write a procedure that simply returns the values selected without doing something more with the data.

Comment: when i write my stored prod i do declare the select statement but informix request i put the outputs into a temp table. i would like to just get an output as if running the query myself.